# Panda df.groupby().max() returning non-existing value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi I am using Groupby function to find out the max value of each brand, but it returns the wrong value for k. The dataset itself doesn't have the value.

already tried to create df.

```
# Group by Brand categories
 brand_groups = crm.groupby("Brand")
 # Apply max function to spend column
 max_spend_by_brand = brand_groups['12month spend','24month spend'].max()
 max_spend_by_brand

  12 Month Spend 24 Month Spend     
A $ 999,544.00  $ 999,976.00
C $ 999,966.00  $ 999,916.00
K $ 999,911.00  $ 999.00
```

And I did fact-check the raw data, $999.00 is not in anywhere from K brand. The dataset itself doesn't even have it. where did it come from?

Comment: Can you sort the dataframe by the `Spend` columns and show the `.tail()`?

Comment: Also try, `df[df["24 Month Spend"] == "$ 999.00"]. Also you're doing a `max` operation on strings is it? `max(["a", "b", "c"])` will return `"c`"`

Comment: @pissall thanks for getting back to me. I think I know more about the data. the numbers are string. I need to convert them into FLOAT. but i've been running into roadblocks. Do I have to remove $ sign before converting?

Comment: Yes, you do. You can just use `.str.replace("$ ", "").replace(",", "")`